# DataTemplate Namespace Not Found

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following xaml code which is trying to reference the DataTemplate Selector below. However I am getting a namespace error. I have tried the following variations to try to import the Selector class but I keep getting the same error

```
    xmlns:lx="clr-namespace:TimeSheet.Views.DataTemplateSpace"
    xmlns:lx="using:TimeSheet.Views.DataTemplateSpace"
    xmlns:lx="TimeSheet.Views.DataTemplateSpace"

    <lx:DayViewListDataTemplateSelector  x:Key="templateSelector"
              DefaultDataTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultDataTemplate}"
              EditableDataTemplate="{StaticResource EditableDataTemplate}" />
```

Here is the outline of my DataTemplate

```
namespace TimeSheet.Views.DataTemplateSpace
{
    public class DayViewListDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate DefaultDataTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate EditableDataTemplate { get; set; }


        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item,
                   DependencyObject container)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Interestingly when I use the first option. Intellisense helps me out and provides me with the options for the namespace when I create the tag but it still throws the namespace error.

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo. I did try changing the aliases around as well.

Comment: Interesting thing is that with the first option shown above, the intellisense helps me out and provides me with the options but when I try to build it throws errors.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that the namespace is lx, but then calling it using l.

Try:

```
<lx:DayViewListDataTemplateSelector  x:Key="templateSelector"
          DefaultDataTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultDataTemplate}"
          EditableDataTemplate="{StaticResource EditableDataTemplate}" />
```